# Why does rabbitmq message appear null to queue consumer in laravel

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, queue

I have a project setup with rabbitmq and it works sending messages out and also receiving messages from laravel to laravel using default job handler provided by the package

```
'job' => VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Jobs\RabbitMQJob::class,
```

But I want to receive messages from python or even from the rabbitmq dashboard itself,

Thus, I configured my job handler

```
'job' => \App\Jobs\RabbitMQJob::class,


use VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\Queue\Jobs\RabbitMQJob as BaseJob;

class RabbitMQJob extends BaseJob
{

    /**
     * Fire the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function fire()
    {
        $payload = $this->payload();

        Log::notice($payload);
        
        $class = HandlePythonResponse::class;
        $method = 'handle';

        ($this->instance = $this->resolve($class))->{$method}($this, $payload);
       
        $this->delete();
    }
}
```

Each time I send a message to this app, I get the following error

```
[2022-04-28 12:01:33] local.ERROR: Trying to access array offset on value of type null {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Trying to access array offset on value of type null at /Users/angwamosees/Documents/moses/app1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php:315)
```

Please does anyone have any idea why rabbit mq send null mnessages

Answer (score 1):

After struggling to debug what the problem is, I understood that the format of data to be passed from rabbitmq to laravel must be JSON format. And must carry job and uuid as part of the payload. I hope this helps someone later in the future. The format looks like this

```
{
    "job":"job_name",
    "data":90,
    "uuid":"uuid-equivalent-value"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for research! Don't you know how to consume plain messages using Laravel Queue and `vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq`?